# Unable to parse locally stored JSON file with special character like backslash "\" in R

Tags: json, r, mailchimp

I am not able to parse locally stored JSON file which looks something like this-

```
[{"status_code":200,"operation_id":"13-10","response":"{\"emails\":
[{\"campaign_id\":\"1111111\",\"email_address\":\"1111@111\",\"activity\":
[]},{\"campaign_id\":\"22222\",\"email_address\":\"2222@2222\",\"activity\":[]}}}]
```

I am using jsonlite
As you can see this `\` is present everywhere, and I am unable to parse it. 
And when I do -

```
st<-fromJSON("/Users/frantr/this_is_R/open_files/json_file.json")
print(st)
```

I get this-

```
 $ : chr "[{\"status_code\":200"
 $ : chr "\"operation_id\":\"13-10\""
 $ : chr "\"response\":\"{\\\"emails\\\":    [{\\\"campaign_id\\\":\\\"1111111\\\""
 $ : chr "\\\"email_address\\\":\\\"111111111\\\""
 $ : chr "\\\"activity\\\":[]}"
```

Can anyone please help., thank you.

Comment: Where did this string come from? Is your *file* like this or did you check a value in the watch window? Do you get an actual error? `\ ` is the escape characters used in strings, that allows you to enter really special characters like `"`. it does *not* actually exist in the string. BTW all programming languages have a way to escape special characters. In R, C, C++, C#, Java, Markdown and others, that character is `\`

Comment: My file is like this only, and how do I convert this json file to csv format, with the 3 columns as "email_address","campaign_id","Activity" ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check how your JSON string is generated? There were a couple of issues with it, such as an extra `"` before the first internal `{` (after `response:`), and a missing `]`.

Then, as you suspected the `\` was causing an issue. So I'm using `readLines` and removing the `\` in one step. This JSON can then be read using `jsonlite::fromJSON`

For example, I have a file on my desktop called `myJson.json`, which contains this string

```
[{"status_code":200,"operation_id":"13-10","response":{\"emails\":[{\"campaign_id\":\"1111111\",\"email_address\":\"1111@111\",\"activity\":[]},{\"campaign_id\":"22222\",\"email_address\":\"2222@2222\",\"activity\":[]}]}}]
```

I can then read it in using

```
lst <- fromJSON(gsub("\\\\","",readLines("~/Desktop/myJson.json")))

str(lst)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
#   $ status_code : int 200
# $ operation_id: chr "13-10"
# $ response    :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ emails:List of 1
# .. ..$ :'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. ..$ campaign_id  : chr  "1111111" "22222"
# .. .. ..$ email_address: chr  "1111@111" "2222@2222"
# .. .. ..$ activity     :List of 2
# .. .. .. ..$ : list()
# .. .. .. ..$ : list()
```

You can then get whatever components/data you want from this list

```
lst$response$emails

# [[1]]
# campaign_id email_address activity
# 1     1111111      1111@111     NULL
# 2       22222     2222@2222     NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but I am doing  fromjson file from locally saved json file  like this -                                                                                 lst<-fromJSON("/Users/frantr/this_is_R/open_files/json_file.json")                              But lst is not a list, it is a data frame, a very weird data frame. Could you please help me on this, thank you .

Comment: Yes I am using jsonlite and i did this -                                                                st<-fromJSON("/Users/frantr/this_is_R/open_files/json_file.json").

Comment: I have updated the question and shown the output, thank you.

Comment: No I have not, I wanted to upvote your answer and by mistake I did that, Sorry.

Comment: Could you please help me with my doubt? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have been very helpful.

Comment: I did as you wrote but I get this error and warning -                                                               Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
          d":"13-10","response":"{"emails":[{"campaign_id":"1111111
                     (right here) ------^
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines("/Users/frantr/this_is_R/open_files/myFILE.json") :
  incomplete final line found on '/Users/frantr/this_is_R/open_files/myFILE.json'

Comment: (right here) ------^   is directly below the "m" of "emails", thank you.

Comment: @frant - notice in my JSON string I don't have the `"` before the `{"emails"`.

Comment: I removed " before ("emails" , but I got this error -                  Error: parse error: premature EOF
                                       [{"status_code":200,"operation_
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: (right here) ------^   is right below  "{" in    " [{"status "    Thank you

Comment: @frant In the first line of my answer I also say you have a missing `]` - it should be the 4th character form the end.

Answer (score 1):

This can help i guess .

```
library(RJSONIO)

    file <- '[{"status_code":200,"operation_id":"13-10","response":"{\"emails\":[{\"campaign_id\":\"1111111\",\"email_address\":\"1111@111\",\"activity\":[]},{\"campaign_id\":\"22222\",\"email_address\":\"2222@2222\",\"activity\":[]}}}]'

    json <- fromJSON(file, nullValue = NA)

    dat <- lapply(json, function(j) {
      as.data.frame(replace(j, sapply(j, is.list), NA))
    })


    library(plyr)
    res <- rbind.fill(dat)

    > res
      status_code operation_id response
    1         200        13-10       NA
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I just want to ask you one question, how do I convert this json file to csv format, with the 3 columns as "email_address","campaign_id","Activity" ? Thank you.

Comment: by converting it into data frame first and then write it as csv .`res <- data.frame(rbind.fill(dat))` and `write.csv(res,"res.csv",row.names = F)`

Answer (score 1):

first of all your json is not valid
i have validated your json:

```
[{"status_code":200,"operation_id":"13-10","response":"{\"emails\":[{\"campaign_id\":\"1111111\",\"email_address\":\"1111@111\",\"activity\":[]},{\"campaign_id\":\"22222\",\"email_address\":\"2222@2222\",\"activity\":[]}]}"}]
```

and used jsonlite package to load it and it is working fine:

```
library(jsonlite)
json = fromJSON("pathTofile.json")
json

  status_code operation_id
1         200        13-10
                                                                                                                                           response
1 {"emails":[{"campaign_id":"1111111","email_address":"1111@111","activity":[]},{"campaign_id":"22222","email_address":"2222@2222","activity":[]}]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I just want to ask you one question, how do I convert this json file to csv format, with the 3 columns as "email_address","campaign_id","Activity" ? Thank you.